# How to record origin each transmitter seperately [OMNET++]

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

- I have a simulation with 3 transmitters and 1 receiver.

How do I setup vector recording so that at the receiver, each transmitter signal is recorded separately.
I only want to record received data at the receiver.

Right now I run:
`receivervector.record((long)1);`

Vector statistic recorded:

- receiver[0].packetsreceived

In my resulting output is that the receiver will record "1" for every transmitter it hears instead of 3 separate statistics for each transmitter.

Optimal result is:

- receiver[0].packetsreceived from transmitter1
- receiver[0].packetsreceived from transmitter2
- receiver[0].packetsreceived from transmitter3